# What does it mean for a complex linear functional to be positive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading Rudin: real and complex analysis chapter 2. On page 35 there is an example which I could not understand: let $C$ be the set of all continuous complex functions on $[0, 1]$, and define $$\Lambda f = \int_0^1f(x)dx\;\;(f\in 
 C)$$
where integral is Riemann integral. Rudin says $\Lambda$ is a "positive linear functional" since "$\Lambda f\geq 0$ whenever $f\geq 0$".

Here is my question: since $f$ is complex valued function, what does it mean to say $f\geq 0$ (I am assuming $0$ here means the zero function?), given that complex combers has no total ordering? And since   $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ can be complex valued, what does it mean to say $\Lambda f\geq 0$?

A related question: on page 42, 2.14, the Riesz representation theorem, $C_c(X)$ is assumed to be a space of complex functions (page 39), so how should I understand what is a "positive linear functional" on this set?

Comment: One says that a complex number is positive if it is real and positive. Same for functions: A complex valued function is positive if it only takes positive values.

Comment: Moishe Kohan is correct, and in fact Rudin says exactly this in Chapter 1 (the top of page 8 in my copy): "For a complex function $f$, the statement '$f\geq 0$' means that all values $f(x)$ of $f$ are non-negative real numbers."